# Flutter build fails [Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.]

Tags: firebase, flutter

I had no issues yesterday, today my build failed for no obvious reasons. And I just upgraded flutter, and other plugins, and I'm still unable to build my current flutter project which uses the following firebase packages

```
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.14
  firebase_core: ^1.14.1
  firebase_database: ^9.0.11
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.12
```

console

```
   Building with sound null safety 

Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:15: error: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins does not exist
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin;
                                          ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:16: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
                               ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:17: error: package io.flutter.plugin.common does not exist
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
                               ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
public class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
                                                  ^
  symbol: class FlutterPlugin
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:29: error: package MethodChannel does not exist
public class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin implements FlutterPlugin, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
                                                                              ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
  private MethodChannel channel;
          ^
  symbol:   class MethodChannel
  location: class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onAttachedToEngine(FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
                                 ^
  symbol:   class FlutterPluginBinding
  location: class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class FlutterPluginBinding
  location: class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:217: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, @NonNull final MethodChannel.Result result) {
                           ^
  symbol:   class MethodCall
  location: class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:217: error: package MethodChannel does not exist
  public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, @NonNull final MethodChannel.Result result) {
                                                                        ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:63: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    channel = new MethodChannel(binding.getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL_NAME);
                  ^
  symbol:   class MethodChannel
  location: class FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:70: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:216: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-1.14.1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.java:220: error: illegal parenthesized expression
    switch (call.method) {
           ^
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
15 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_core:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           11.3s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':src')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
...
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.XXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.1.0')

}
```

Things I have tried:

- reinstalling flutter, dart, and kotlin
- flutter clean
- dart clean
- dart pub cache repair
- dart pub cache clean
- invalidating cache

Thank you for any suggestions

**[Update].** The problem seems to be my lib's folder! I had made a change to one of the directory names in the lib folder. And this problem began to appear. Even though I manually updated all package import URIs. Transferring the lib folder into a new project persists the problem, reverting the name changes still has no effect. What am I missing

Error: The argument type 'List<StoreOrderEntity/*1*/>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<StoreOrderEntity/*2*/>'.

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

- Dart analyzer doesn't complain.
- This exception only happens during build. And build fails
- It started to occur after I changed some directory names in my lib, reverting back doesn't seem to solve it

Comment: it seems the problem originated on firebase_core and given that you upgraded your packages, you can try using an older version of firebase_core and try to build it.

Comment: I would have considered that. But since the problem arose before I upgrade the packages, I'm a bit skeptical to consider downgrading, I feel like something else is causing this trouble

Comment: sorry I just noticed that you added firebase bom on your build.gradle file... can you try commenting out all related to firebase on both project and app level... and  try to build it again if there's change on the error kindly update your question...

Comment: @KeiCredo thank you for replying back. I just tried what you suggested by removing my entire lib folder and leave the main class only, the error still persists and nothing in the stack trace changes

Comment: I made an update..

Comment: Can you try my posted answer it seems there was a miscommunication regarding my suggestion earlier. I'll update the posted answer to cater your updated question if the problems still persist.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution to the problem you have before the update on your lib folder. And it is commenting out all firebase code in `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle` similar to this:

`android/build.gradle`

[image]

`android/app/build.gradle`

[image]

After doing this do a flutter clean just to be safe then a rebuild.

Comment: Thank you @KeiCredo for the reply. Although I don't have the lines you have commented out, but I found no solution to this weird behavior of flutter. I created a new project and I'm transferring individual files. It's so weird..

Comment: I viewed my changes on my github repo, there were some accidental name changes inside the build gradle file (it has happened because of my refactoring). I reverted the changes but it had no effect. The change in the name of the directory (as I mentioned previously) seemed to be the causing issue, which doesn't make sense per se